# Having() count of id's on joined table

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to make this query in OrmLite:

```sql
select b.* from blog b
join blog_to_blog_category btbc on b.id = btbc.blog_id
join blog_category bc on btbc.blog_category_id = bc.id
where b.url like '%.com' and bc.id in (100, 583)
group by b.id
having count(distinct bc.id ) = 1
```

I can't figure out how to get the Having() method structured.  I can see there is a `Sql.CountDistinct()` method but I can't figure out how to use it with Having().

I figure I need to do something along the lines of:

```cs
var q = db
.From<Blog>()
.LeftJoin<BlogToBlogCategory>()
.Join<BlogToBlogCategory, BlogCategory>()
.Where<BlogCategory>(x => Sql.In(x.Id, 100, 583))
.GroupBy<Blog>(bc => bc.Id)
.Having(x => Sql.CountDistinct("blog_category.id") == "2")
```

This gives error:

> 42883: operator does not exist: bigint = text

I can't see how to type it to take a table column name and return a number for comparison.

Is this query possible?

***EDIT***

I got around it by setting having expression explicitly

```cs
q.HavingExpression = $"having count(distinct {q.Table<BlogCategory>()}.{q.Column<BlogCategory>(bc => bc.Id)}) = 2";
```

I am still curious though if it is possible to do this with fluent api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added multiple typed table overloads for `Having()` in the latest v5.11.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) which will allow you to reference a joined table properties in a typed expression, e.g:

```
var q = db
    .From<Blog>()
    .LeftJoin<BlogToBlogCategory>()
    .Join<BlogToBlogCategory, BlogCategory>()
    .Where<BlogCategory>(x => Sql.In(x.Id, 100, 583))
    .GroupBy<Blog>(bc => bc.Id)
    .Having<BlogCategory>(x => Sql.CountDistinct(x.Id) == 2)
```